# tflearn throws invalid argument error in CNN training

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, tflearn

I was going through the CNN tutorial by sentdex and this is the code that i wrote on my system to train the model.

```
model.fit({'input': X}, {'targets': Y}, n_epoch=5, validation_set=({'input': test_x}, {'targets': test_y}), 
snapshot_step=500, show_metric=True, run_id=MODEL_NAME)
```

This gives me an invalid argument error:

> You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'input_1/X' with dtype
>   float [[Node: input_1/X = Placeholderdtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[],
>   _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]]

I am using python 3.5 in windows 10 and tensorflow 1.1.0 and tflearn 0.3.1

These are the data variables

```
X = np.array([i[0] for i in train]).reshape(-1,IMG_SIZE,IMG_SIZE,1)
Y = [i[1] for i in train]

test_x = np.array([i[0] for i in test]).reshape(-1,IMG_SIZE,IMG_SIZE,1)
test_y = [i[1] for i in test]
```

And the following is the convnet architecture code:

```
import tflearn

from tflearn.layers.conv import conv_2d, max_pool_2d
from tflearn.layers.core import input_data, dropout, fully_connected
from tflearn.layers.estimator import regression


convnet = input_data(shape=[None, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 1], name='input')

convnet = conv_2d(convnet, 32, 2, activation='relu')
convnet = max_pool_2d(convnet, 2)

convnet = conv_2d(convnet, 64, 2, activation='relu')
convnet = max_pool_2d(convnet, 2)

convnet = fully_connected(convnet, 1024, activation='relu')
convnet = dropout(convnet, 0.8)

convnet = fully_connected(convnet, 2, activation='softmax')
convnet = regression(convnet, optimizer='adam', learning_rate=LR, 
loss='categorical_crossentropy', name='targets')

model = tflearn.DNN(convnet,tensorboard_dir='log')
```

Comment: Would you mind add some code to show what the variables in your code are?

Comment: i have edited the post with the convnet architecture and the input and target variables for train and test set. I am new to stack overflow so had to make changes in the post instead of posting them here.